# Удаление слов из списка, соответствующих набору слов из другого списка (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, list

У меня есть список с индексами и предложениями, разбитыми по словам. Пример элемента списка: `['2617', ['two', 'green','blowflies', 'paris','texas']` И есть список с так же разбитыми по словам именованными сущностями и т.д., которые нужно удалить из первого списка, то есть в результате получить `['2617, ['two', 'green', 'blowflies']`  - из примера выше нужно будет убрать `['paris', 'texas']`.
Вот мой код:

```
def delete(dirty_split, bad_words_split):
    without_bad = []
    for row, words in tqdm(itertools.zip_longest(dirty_split, bad_words_split)):
        sentence = row[1]
        result = [(lambda x: re.sub(r'|'.join(words), '', x))(x) for x in sentence]
        result = [x for x in result if x] # удаление пустых токенов
        without_bad.append([row[0], result])
    return without_bad
```

Однако на каком-то этапе происходит выпадение с `error: nothing to repeat at position 13`, подозреваю, что дело может быть в спец.символах, которые затесались в один из списков, можно их как-то взять в расчет тоже?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если не важен порядок слов, то можно преобразовать списки в `set`-ы и выполнить операцию вычитания множеств:

```
    list(set(dirty_split) - set(bad_words_split))
```

Если все слова в `dirty_split` различны, то можно просто модифицировать этот список следующим кодом:

```
    for word in bad_words_split:
        dirty_split.remove(word)
```